# Gem5 Full System simulation hangs in middle of print statement

Tags: x86, kvm, gem5

I have a gem5 full system setup that creates a checkpoint using KVM X86 cores and then boots from checkpoint using atomic and later switches to O3 cores at ROI. All this while using classical memory model.

For some benchmarks it works well but for others it seems to hang in the middle of a print statement in the benchmark. I have that this problem mainly happens to splash benchmarks.

Has anyone faced a similar problem? Any ideas what might be the problem or where I should start looking?

It is also worth mentioning that the problem is not consistent. Sometimes recreating the checkpoint fixes/breaks a previous run. I have also tried skipping the checkpointing step but nothing changed.

Comment: I would recommend adding the "KVM X86 full system O3" restore keywords to the title. I would also do an instruction trace to see where it hangs. What do you mean by in the "middle of the print statement"? There is a `printf` and only part of the output appears on the terminal?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, only part of the output of a printf message is printed.